# Saltstack with AWS Autoscaling Groups

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-sns, salt-stack, salt-cloud

My objective is to setup automatic node recovery upon failover. I came across ec2-autoscale-reactor formula in Salt that ties with Autoscaling Groups in AWS.

This mandates AWS SNS Service to issue notifications over HTTP(s) to Salt Master when a node is created or deleted. However, AWS SNS needs a publicly-open host to send notifictions; hence this may not be a solution as my Salt Master shall be local within VPC.

Is there any other option in Salt using which I may achieve automatic-node-healing for components in AWS?